APScheduler jobstore
is it possible to add a new field to the DjangoJob model in django-apscheduler?
I want to add a new field to relate it to another model, or if it's not possible to add, can I use a custom model instead of the default one?
If it's possible, how can it be done?

Hi welcome to [so]. Please take a moment to have a quick [tour] of the site. If you want to ask a question see [ask]. Kindly add a [example] to your questions to make it answerable.
